# Sort table in ssrs for an aggregate field

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, aggregate

I have a column that returns me tasks to find out how many there are I do a CountDistinct (id_tarefa). I need to sort the table by this larger field for the lower value of count (), but the SSRS does not accept sorting by field that has aggregate function.

It is possible to do this sort?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible - but you cannot sort the table by using an aggregate function.

The trick is to sort on the **Group** and not the table. **Row Group -> Group Properties** then the Sorting tab.